# How to specify model to a ngInclude directive in AngularJS?

Tags: html, templates, angularjs

I would like to use the same HTML template in 3 places, just each time with a different model.
I know I can access the variables from the template, but there names will be different.

Is there a way to pass a model to the ngInclude?

This is what I would like to achieve, of course the attribute add-variable does not work now. Then in my included template, I would acces the detailsObject and its properties.

```
<pane title="{{projectSummary.ProjectResults.DisplayName}}">
    <h2>{{projectSummary.ProjectResults.DisplayName}}</h2>
    <ng-include src="'Partials/SummaryDetails.html'" init-variable="{'detailsObject': projectSummary.ProjectResults}"></ng-include>
</pane>

<pane  title="Documents" header="true"></pane>

<pane ng-repeat="document in projectSummary.DocumentResults" title="{{document.DisplayName}}">
    <h2>{{document.DisplayName}}</h2>
    <ng-include src="'Partials/SummaryDetails.html'" add-variable="{'detailsObject': document}"></ng-include>
</pane>

<pane ng-repeat="header in [1]" title="Languages" header="true"></pane>

<pane ng-repeat="language in projectSummary.ResultsByLanguagePairs" title="{{language.DisplayName}}">
    <h2>{{document.DisplayName}}</h2>
    <ng-include src="'Partials/SummaryDetails.html'" add-variable="{'detailsObject': language}"></ng-include>
</pane>
```

If I took a bad approach with using ng-include, is there something else I should try?

Comment: It seems like you need a directive ?

Comment: A solution is create a new directive, as i said in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36916276/2516399

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**NOTE: this is not my original answer but this is how I'd do this after using angular for a bit.**

I would create a directive with the html template as the markup passing in the dynamic data to the directive as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMmyY/141/).

Steps/notes for this example:

1. Define a directive with markup in the `templateUrl` and attribute(s) used to pass data into the directive (named `type` in this example).
2. Use the directive data in the template (named `type` in this example).
3. When using the directive in the markup make sure you pass in the data from the controller scope to the directive (`<address-form type="billing"></address-form>` (where billing is accessing an object on the controller scope).
4. Note that when defining a directive the name is camel cased but when used in the markup it is lower case dash delimited (ie it's named `addressForm` in the js but `address-form` in the html). More info on this can be found in the angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Here is the js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').directive('addressForm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/addressform.html', // markup for template
        scope: {
            type: '=' // allows data to be passed into directive from controller scope
        }
    };
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    // sample objects in the controller scope that gets passed to the directive
    $scope.billing = { type: 'billing type', value: 'abc' };
    $scope.delivery = { type: 'delivery type', value: 'def' };
});
```

With markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <address-form type="billing"></address-form>
    <address-form type="delivery"></address-form>
</div>
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (which is completely different than using a directive BTW).**

Note: The fiddle from my original answer below doesn't appear to work anymore due to an error (but keeping it here in case it is still useful)

There was a discussion about this on the Google Group you can [see it here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/5clM0kjHXq8/discussion).

It looks like this functionality is not supported out of the box but you can use Brice's patch as described in [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/5clM0kjHXq8/5Wj5716_QikJ).

Here is the sample code from his [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briceburg/NMmyY/1/):

```
<script id="partials/addressform.html" type="text/ng-template">
    partial of type {{type}}<br>
</script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ng-include src="'partials/addressform.html'" onInclude="type='billing'"></ng-include>
  <ng-include src="'partials/addressform.html'" onLoad="type='delivery'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to achieve it without a new directive, with a ng-init. In this ng-init, I create the objectDetails variable and init it to what I want.

Comment: Nowadays you can use your own _directive_ and in it use the _templateUrl_ property.

Comment: using `type='delivery'` just gives me the word `delivery`, not the `delivery` value from the controller. -1

Comment: @Imray I've changed the answer to use a directive instead which should fix the issue you were having with just passing a word instead of the value from the controller. Thanks for letting me know the existing answer was not quite working anymore.

Comment: @Gloopy I need to add some other data along with billing also. Let say some $scope.name="Ankur" and I cannot afford to do type="name" as it will generate the view again. What to do in this regard?

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMmyY/164/) help at all? you can add as many properties to the object being bound.

Comment: @Gloopy I don't want it in the same object due to some restrictions. But i want to use certain scope property inside the view.

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal you can pass in more data via a different object to the directive [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NMmyY/165/)

Comment: I've been putting off learning directives for some time. This was a great introduction into it. I'll be using directives liberally in the future. I'd recommend this approach even if you haven't touched directives before.

Answer (score 61):

There is a rather simple solution, although I must admit, it's not what Misko would recommend. But if creating a directive is an overkill for you and getting Brice's patch is not feasible then the following will help you.

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['A']" ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>
<div ng-repeat="name in ['B']" ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partial.html">
   <div>{{ name }}</div>
</script>
```

It's quite evident why it works. See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cndc6/4/

Comment: That is really quite brilliant and requires no modifications to angular or new directives.

Comment: This worked very well for me with complex data structures as well.

Comment: This is the best hack by far until Angular adds support passing params to partials.

Comment: Truly brilliant, and not that much of a hack either.

Comment: Thank you for this!  If my mind had gone down this route, I probably would've first tried to use 'ngInit', but this automatically makes a "transcluded" scope which 'ngInit' does not do.

Answer (score 14):

There is a pull to fix this but it looks like it's dead:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1227

Without modifying the Angular source code this will solve the problem in a reusable not-too-hacky-feeling way:

```
directive('newScope', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        priority: 450,
    };
});
```

And an example:

```
<div new-scope ng-init="myVar = 'one instance'" ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
<div new-scope ng-init="myVar = 'another instance'" ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
```

Here is a Plunker of it in action:
http://plnkr.co/edit/El8bIm8ta97MNRglfl3n

Comment: Works great, thank you. For me it looks nicer if I get rid of _ng-init_ and just have **<div new-scope="myVar = 'one instance'" ng-include="'template.html'"></div>**. (I just copied two lines of code from _ng-init_ to your directive to get this to work)

Answer (score 6):

```
<div new-scope="myVar = 'one instance'" ng-include="'template.html'"></div>

directive('newScope', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        priority: 450,
        compile: function () {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.newScope);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

This is a directive that combines `new-scope` from [John Culviner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315914/3116322) with code from Angular's `ng-init`.

For completeness, this is the [Angular 1.2 26 ng-init source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/master/1.2.26/angular.js), you can see the only change in the new-scope directive is the addition of `scope: true`

```
{
  priority: 450,
  compile: function() {
    return {
      pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Quick'n'dirty solution:

```
<div ng-init="details=document||language||projectSummary.ProjectResults">
```

Comment: Not a bad workaround so your div is outside each ng-include and you are setting each one explicitly to either documents, language, or projectSummary.ProjectResults?

Comment: Actually i put this inside the html template, because I am lazy. But writing it before each ng-Include div would be cleaner.

Comment: Would this init the value in correct scope? I.e. does it set the value in the scope of the include?

Comment: This line is actually inside the inner html template, so yes, the scope is correct.

Comment: This is what i was literally looking for i have no idea why i didn't know this already lol. Though this is the best answer on this question so far.

Answer (score 1):

I hear you! ng-include is not that reusable because it has access to the global scope. It's a little weird.

There should be a way to set local variables. [Using a new directive instead of ng-include](http://tech.fongmun.com/post/131863914487/scoping-variables-in-ng-include-without-ng-repeat) is a cleaner solution.

The ideal usage looks like:

```
<div ng-include-template="'Partials/SummaryDetails.html'" ng-include-variables="{ 'detailsObject': language }"></div>
```

The directive is:

```
.directive(
  'ngIncludeTemplate'
  () ->
    {
      templateUrl: (elem, attrs) -> attrs.ngIncludeTemplate
      restrict: 'A'
      scope: {
        'ngIncludeVariables': '&'
      }
      link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        vars = scope.ngIncludeVariables()
        for key, value of vars
          scope[key] = value
    }
)
```

You can see that the directive doesn't use the global scope. Instead, it reads the object from ng-include-variables and add those members to its own local scope.

It's clean and generic.