# AngularJS - load dynamic template HTML within directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which loads content from an external HTML file.  Passed into this directive is some scope data which is used in the rendering of that HTML fragment.  e.g.

`<div class="{{cls}}" data-obj="{{obj}}" data-id="{{id}}">`

`<!-- remainder of content here -->`

`</div>`

What I would like to do within this directive is to load a further HTML partial within this based on the original scope data passed into the directive.  I can't seem to get this to work, but it should be something along the lines of the following:

`<div class="{{cls}}" data-obj="{{obj}}" data-id="{{id}}">`

`<!-- remainder of content here -->`

`<div ng-include="partials/{{obj}}.html></div>`

`</div>`

Using this, the file doesn't get included, but I don't get any errors either.  Can anybody assist me here?

**NB**: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422966/how-to-specify-model-to-a-nginclude-directive-in-angularjs), which is a similar issue, but hasn't helped me.

**UPDATE** - I noticed in Chrome dev tools that the URL is being resolved as expected, but the file contents are not getting included.  I thought from the docs that `ng-include` loaded and compiled the requested fragment, so I was expecting this to work.

Answer (score 17):

Found a solution in the end, by declaring the following in the directive:

```
<div ng-include src="view.getView()"></div>
```

and the following in the directive controller:

```
$scope.view = {
    getView: function() {
        return "partials/" + $scope.obj + ".html";
    }
};
```

Works perfectly now!

Comment: You can simplify this a little, the issue is that it expects a string, not objects:                                              
`<div ng-include src="'partials/'+{{obj}}+'.html'"></div>`. 
Notice that I put single quotes around any normal text, this is what you need to force it from object literals to a string.

Answer (score 1):

In comment on the comment of Shane Gadsby: it is not `<div ng-include src="'partials/'+{{obj}}+'.html'"></div>` but `<div ng-include src="'partials/'+obj+'.html'"></div>`.
Your comment explains why *'this is what you need to force it from object literals to a string'*, so everything not in single quotes is handled by the compiler as a scope object.