# ng-include on load with an object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

This works

```
<div ng-include="template.html" onload="person='Jane'"></div>
```

^ This sets the local scope variable `person` in the include to 'Jane' (string)

But I want to pass a person object that is called `user`: `{name: 'Jane' }`

```
<div ng-include="template.html" onload="person=user"></div>
```

^ This sets the local scope variable `person` in the include to be 'undefined'

How is it possible to pass an object as a local variable to ng-include?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422966/how-to-specify-model-to-a-nginclude-directive-in-angularjs

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  Correct me if I'm wrong, `ng-init` is not solving it for me, let me see if I can get a jsfiddle going to demonstrate

Comment: A solution is create a new directive, as i said in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36916276/2516399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you actually want is a custom directive:

```
<div person-directive="{name:'Jane'}"></div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('personDirective',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            person: '=personDirective'
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html'
    };
});
```

With this, you bind the passed-in value to `person` in the loaded template.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/p64p4/)

Comment: yep, directive works, just seemed like a little overkill, thought I could get away with ng-include.

Comment: Overkill? Not really.

Answer (score 1):

ng-include is not that reusable because it doesn't offer a way to set local variables. Using onload is bad because it litters the global scope. If the example gets a little more complicated, it'll fail.

[Making a new directive instead of using ng-include](http://tech.fongmun.com/post/131863914487/scoping-variables-in-ng-include-without-ng-repeat) is a cleaner solution.

The ideal usage looks like:

```
<div ng-include-template="template.html" ng-include-variables="{ person: 'Jane' }"></div>
<div ng-include-template="template.html" ng-include-variables="{ person: user }"></div>
```

The directive is:

```
.directive(
  'ngIncludeTemplate'
  () ->
    {
      templateUrl: (elem, attrs) -> attrs.ngIncludeTemplate
      restrict: 'A'
      scope: {
        'ngIncludeVariables': '&'
      }
      link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        vars = scope.ngIncludeVariables()
        for key, value of vars
          scope[key] = value
    }
)
```

You can see that the directive doesn't use the global scope. Instead, the directive reads the object from ng-include-variables and add those members to its own local scope.

This is clean and generic.

Comment: What does `->` stand for?

Comment: It's a coffeescript. `() -> { ... }` is `function() { ... }`