# What are the best practices of using ngInclude with ControllerAs syntax?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I had the intention to use one template across several views having different controllers.

But now I realize that I cannot  just write universal binding in templates because values will be put inside `$scope.concreteControllerName`.

Angular docs for [ngInclude](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) say that

> This directive creates new scope.

I could use `ng-init` directive and pass controller instance to template's scope:

```
<ng-include src="..." ng-init="controller=concreteControllerName"/>
```

or even better

```
<ng-include src="..." ng-init="model=getModelForTemplate()"/>
```

and then write `{{controller.boundvalue}}` in template.

That is a working solution, I guess.

And here I'd like to know whether other better approaches exist and if not, should templates always be used with some notion of passed model to abstract away from parent scope?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422966/how-to-specify-model-to-a-nginclude-directive-in-angularjs/20639139#20639139) - several answers there are great.

Answer (score 3):

Use John Papa's [controllerAs View Syntax](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y030) and [controllerAs with vm](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y032). You specify different controllers in the `ng-include` directives but use the same src html template. The common `vm` variable name is used in the template.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-include ng-controller="controllerOne as vm" src="'same.html'"></div>
<div ng-include ng-controller="controllerTwo as vm" src="'same.html'"></div>
<div ng-include ng-controller="controllerThree as vm" src="'same.html'"></div>
```

**controllerOne.js**

```
function controllerOne() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = 'Controller One!';
```

**sharedTemplate.html**

```
<div>{{vm.name}}</div>
```

**Here is a full working version: [Full Working Code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UQiASPDpUaBY7tSvWyi?p=preview)**

Comment: It would be nice, in your Plunker, to show how you'd refer to the parent controller from the child controller (without using $scope).