# It is possible to make a template and pass parameters to it in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, frontend

I'm working on a social app about image posts, and we have to show these posts in multiple screens in the app. The problem is, we are repeating the posts' structure in every screen template, so if we make a change to the structure of the post in some template we have to change that in every template.

My question is, it is possible to create a template -in this case the posts' structure- and send the post object as a parameter so this new template can load it correctly? And of course, call this template everywhere we need it, something like Django blocks and template inheritance. Is there a way to do that in Angular? Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with existing templates like mustache?

Comment: Here's the possitble solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21315914/2431110

Comment: are you talking about angular templates or html generated by your backend

Comment: I'm talking about Angular templates, there is no backend in this project.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, I think that you need to use directive

**Script**

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer></div>
</div>
```

**template**

```
Name: Naomi Address: 1600 Amphitheatre
```

The link with the documentation is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

**UPDATE 1**

based on your question, you can pass and object to the directive for that you need do something like the following code.

```
myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{obj.prop}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = { prop: "world" };
});
```

Comment: I need to pass the directive an object with a lot of properties, can I assign that object to the directive scope or something like that?